# woocommerce widget title has no html or css tags to target

Tags: woocommerce

I have struggled for a while to find a solution for this and decided to turn to you.
I have placed some woocommerce widgets in a sidebar and I have a issue styling those widgets. My problem is that the widget title has no html tags or css class for me to target. You can see below.

```html
<div class="wrap contentclass" role="document">
<div id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="main col-lg-9 col-md-8" role="main">
<aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 kad-sidebar" role="complementary">
<div class="sidebar">
Cart
<div class="hide_cart_widget_if_empty">
Products
<ul class="product_list_widget">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
Product Categories
<select class="dropdown_product_cat" name="product_cat">
</div>
</aside>
```

Comment: That's some bad HTML :( If targeting the parent div isn't enough, I'm not sure anything can be done without JavaScript

Comment: I haven't done any alterations to the out of the box woocommerce plugin or widgets. I use the virtue theme on my site which is supposed to work with woocommerce, or so they say. How should I go about fixing this problem?